# Connect two pipes that do not line up

Tags: faucet, copper, hose

Not a plumbing whiz, so I thought I'd pose my issue here.

I have a 12in Shark bite sillcock that runs through my brick foundation for an outdoor hose. Once inside, it connects to the existing copper line, which is immediately to the right.

[image]

Problem is that the sillcock is a bit too long. The faucet sticks out about two inches from the brick foundation. Obviously, if I try to push it closer towards the foundation it puts pressure on the copper line.

Is there anyway to work around this? My only thought would be to take the sillcock out, buy a shorter one, and install it with just enough copper line on the end to enter the basement. But would that defeat the purpose of the "frost-proof" sillcock?

Comment: I was looking at the 1st fitting after the sharkbite elbow and when I enlarged that picture it looks like it may be a black iron fitting. If I am wrong, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Change/turn the T fitting 90 degrees so it's directing the water perpendicularly away from the wall, then 90 degree elbow towards the faucet, then 90 again.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest cheapest hacky thing I can think of:

Disconnect copper pipe between the sillcock and the ball valve.
Push the sillcock all the way into the wall and anchor it there.

Go out and buy a piece of PEX pipe (or flexible copper, but pex is easier). Aim the 90 degree L on the sillcock upwards.  Connect the pex up and put a loop in it and have it connect back to the ball valve.  Anchor the PEX to the wall.

This will also help your sillcock survive freezing temps.

Comment: Does the ball valve look wrong wont drain sillcock,Maybe could leave it  for shut off. And add a fitting to drain out of pex and sillcock.

Answer (score 0):

Any way looks like you did it, and used shark bite fittings. Seems like ball valve is wrong, you should be able to shut off water and open the little drain to let the water out off the sillcock for the winter. Now it looks like you replace the t fitting,add a 90 fitting.  Replace the ball valve (install so water shuts off ,and you drain sillcock.And maybe a coupling to reuse sillcock.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace that "frost proof" sillcock with a new one of the correct length. By the way, in the picture the 1st fitting appears to be black iron which should not be used on a domestic water system. Make sure that you seal the outside wall access hole to keep out the freezing cold weather.

Comment: I don't see any black iron. Was the photo changed?

Comment: @isherwood Looking at the edit history, no.  I don't see any iron fittings either.

Comment: I was looking at the 1st fitting after the sharkbite elbow and when I enlarged the picture it looked as if that  fitting is black iron. If I am wrong I apologize